# CORS request working with Safari?

Tags: javascript, ajax, safari

I understand why the following snippet doesn't work in Firefox and in Chrome: we're making an AJAX request to another domain.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://www.perdu.com", true);
xhr.addEventListener("load", function() { console.debug(xhr.responseText); }, false);
xhr.send(null);
```

But then why does Safari output this? This is the actual content of the page. I have Safari 7.1.

```
<html><head><title>Vous Etes Perdu ?</title></head><body><h1>Perdu sur l'Internet ?</h1><h2>Pas de panique, on va vous aider</h2><strong><pre>    * <----- vous &ecirc;tes ici</pre></strong></body></html>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior running from localhost on safari 7.0.1. What domain are you executing your request from?

Comment: I can't reproduce it either from localhost but if I right-click the file to open it with Safari it does load the page's content. If I do that with Chrome or Firefox, it doesn't. Is this simply a Safari peculiarity?

Comment: Can you share a screen shot of the network panel in your safari browser? Also can you see if there are any console messages from the browser?
Also just including the CORS browser compatibility reference to aid with answering. http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors

Comment: There is no console message besides the result of the query. Here's the requested screenshot: http://i59.tinypic.com/280p1l1.png

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.perdu.com/. Origin file:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. this is safari result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update

It turns out that Safari behaves differently when loading from a server or from a file system.

The original answer below tests the CORS functionality with a `file:///` scheme. Safari lets users bypass CORS on that scheme.

As Jonathan Crowe pointed out on `localhost`, so with the `http://` scheme, Safari blocks the response, same as Firefox and Chrome.

So there is no bug on this one. As for the behaviour on the file system, I guess we can call it a feature, or a convenience (thinking about quick local tests)?

Note: This update relies on an additional, simple test to serve the HTML snippet below from an HTTP server. Nothing fancy, and Safari just behaves as the others.

### Original answer

I could reproduce the problem. It might be a bug in Safari 7.1, and here is what I found toward that temporary conclusion.

- Not reproducible on Safari 7.0.1 (see comment by Jonathan Crowe).
- Two main differences:

  - Safari is the only browser that does NOT set the `Origin` header. Others set it to `null`.
  - The WebKit versions differ in Safari and Chrome.
- No bug report related to CORS on Apple's [tracking system](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Also, this version of Safari allows setting the `Origin` header on the `XMLHttpRequest` object (Chrome does not):

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Origin", null);
```

Setting the header to `null` to get closer to the other browsers does not change the result: Safari 7.1 still allows the response to get through to the requester.

I could not make sure this is a bug in Safari 7.1, but it seems to be its behaviour right now.

Some details below.

#### Test page and code

```
<html>
  <script>
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://www.perdu.com", true);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function() { console.debug(xhr.responseText); }, false);
    xhr.send(null);
  </script>
</html>
```

#### Tested versions

- Safari 7.1 (9537.85.10.17.1)
- Firefox 33.1
- Chrome 38.0.2125.122

(All on Mac OS X 10.9.5)

#### Firefox request dump

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.perdu.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: null
Connection: keep-alive
```

#### Chrome request dump

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.perdu.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.122 Safari/537.36
Origin: null
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,ja;q=0.4,pt;q=0.2
```

#### Safari request dump

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.perdu.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/600.1.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.1 Safari/537.85.10
Accept-Language: en-us
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

---

#### Note

I am currently testing edge cases with CORS over a range of browsers for a web API. If a bug gets confirmed, it shouldn't be too much of a problem---provided the API security is serious enough (as CORS does not secure the server) !

#### Update

I have asked Apple if they can confirm on their [feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html) site.

Comment: Thanks for your research and expertise! I'll sleep better knowing I'm not the only one to think it's a bug.

Comment: The only thing I'm not really sure is your bit regarding Jonathan Crowe's comment. First of all, it's Safari 7.0.1 he mentions. Secondly, he says he's running from localhost. I can't reproduce the bug from localhost either, only from `file:///…/htdocs/index.html` URLs.

Comment: ① Thanks for your comment, and even selecting this small investigation as an answer. Please change to the "right" answer if any shows up---I am more for a real answer than just a confirmation. ② Thanks for pointing out my mistake on Jonathan's comment. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the 'Disable Local File Restrictions' option enabled in the Develop menu. This will allow CORS requests to go through.

Comment: I didn't know this option, thanks for allowing me to discover it. However I get the same results when it's enabled or disabled.