# Work with JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I'm trying to work with JSON data from API.
Some JSON I can get, and then work with them. But sometimes I have fail: JSON doesn't recognised.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <script>
      $.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%3D%27WRC%27&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback', function(json_data0) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(json_data0));
      });
      
      $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor', function(json_data1){
        alert(JSON.stringify(json_data1));
      });

      $.getJSON('https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker', function(json_data2) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(json_data2));
   });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

QUESTION:
Why does last api doesn't get by getJSON?
The similar situation is for example for https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/

Comment: what do you mean by couple? and why is that sometimes you happen to get data and other times not? is that server problem or client side?

Comment: Job one for any issue in JS, check the console: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.` You're being stopped by the Same Origin Policy

Comment: The first two work, but I get a cross-origin error on the third one :  `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access. `So... well, you're just not allowed to pull this json.

Comment: so, is it ok, that via browser i can see json, but i cant get it to my html page?

Comment: Also remember `$.ajaxSetup({ crossDomain: true; });`

Comment: And, on top of the other issue: The response header of the third API has the Content-Type set to `text/html` rather than `application/json`, which might also let `getJSON` fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is right in the console log ;)

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

This service does not allow other domains to call their API's. This is a *security feature* built into browsers which you cannot disable.

If they wanted to allow access, they would have to add the proper CORS headers to their response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Read more about CORS here: http://enable-cors.org/

Another possibility is to [create a proxy server](http://blog.javascripting.com/2015/01/17/dont-hassle-with-cors/) yourself that would fetch this data and deliver to your browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use CORS request or JSONP. In this case, I think that the best for you is to use JSONP because yahoo apis offer it. Please, read a similar and complete answer that I wrote in the past: [local AJAX-call to remote site works in Safari but not in other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947585/local-ajax-call-to-remote-site-works-in-safari-but-not-in-other-browsers/29995045#29995045)