# Codeigniter/JSON/AJAX - Can't see array data from URL

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, codeigniter

I'm trying to display JSON data using jQuery from a Codeigniter controller. I've already created a JSON URL (http://www.tgttest.jeffreyteruel.com/location/locales), and also have the same data on my WAMP server. What I'm having problems is getting the data to display. It works if I take the same JSON data and place it on a .json file, but I'm looking to get it from a Controller/MySql database.

My code is below:

```
 $.getJSON('http://www.tgttest.jeffreyteruel.com/location/locales', function(data) {
    var output="<ul>";
    for (var i in data.locales) {
        output+="<li>" + data.locales[i].location_id + " " + data.locales[i].location_title  + "</li>";
    }

    output+="</ul>";
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
});
```

It's been a while since I've dealt with AJAX so my skills are rusty. Any help to get the data from the URL is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP. once try jsonp.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CORS or JSONP. Please, read my answer in a similar post:
[local AJAX-call to remote site works in Safari but not in other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947585/local-ajax-call-to-remote-site-works-in-safari-but-not-in-other-browsers/29995045#29995045)